# How do I execute a view in a custom module and print the output (as HTML markup)?

Tags: views, 8, theming

I want to print the output from a simple view in my custom module. But is doesnt work. I have tried many options from forums and stackoverflow. All of them print "array" instead of html-markup.

My controller:

```
class DefaultController extends ControllerBase {


    public function myfunc1() {

        $view = Views::getView('myfirstview');

        $view->setDisplay('page_1');
        $view->preExecute();
        $view->execute();

        // $myresults = $view->preview();  = array
        // $myresults = $view->render();  = array
        $myresults = $view->result; // = array


        return array(
            '#title' => 'Hello World!',
            '#markup' => $myresults,
        );
    }
}
```

How can I print the result/output of a view programmatically?

I dont want to make it without "embed view" , because I want to set some exposed filters later.

Answer (score 2):

Views implements its own render element type ([`Drupal\views\Element\View`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Element%21View.php/class/View/8.4.x)), which you can use like so:

```
return [
  '#title' => 'Hello world',
  'view' => [
    '#type' => 'view',
    '#name' => 'myfirstview',
    '#display_id' => 'page_1',
    '#arguments' => ['foo', 'bar'],
    '#embed' => TRUE,
  ],
];
```

If you need to manipulate the View before rendering it, (you mentioned exposed filters), you can do that first and pass along the object:

```
$view = Views::getView('myfirstview');
$view->setFoo('bar');

return [
  '#type' => 'view',
  '#name' => 'myfirstview',
  '#view' => $view,
  '#display_id' => 'page_1',
  '#embed' => TRUE,
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Notes:
The View has to be a block.
Exposed filters can be added but will not be displayed on your page.
You can set them in your page, eg for a 'severity' field:

```
$filters = $view->getDisplay()->getOption('filters');
$filters['severity']['value'] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]; // include a set of values.
$view->getDisplay()->overrideOption('filters', $filters);
```